# Scala: Syntax of passing an execution context to Future's map function

Tags: scala, future, executioncontext

A previous version of this question did not come to the point, so I tried to boil it down:

The *map* function of a Future takes an ExecutionContext, as shown below (taken of [API 2.10.3](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.concurrent.Future))

```
def map[S](f: (T) ⇒ S)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[S]
```

I want to pass my own ExecutionContext, but I do not succeed. It seems as if I do not get the syntax right.

**How can I pass my ExecutionContext to a map function of a Future?**

What I have got is:

```
val executorService  = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(9)
val executionContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(executorService)

def myFunction(mt : MyType): Unit = println("my function")
def getSomeFuture()(executor: ExecutionContext): Future[MyType] = {..}

// function is served by my execution context. A Future is returned.
val f = getSomeFuture()(executionContext)

// compiles if I provide the standard global execution context - sth. I do NOT want
f map (myFunction)

// does not compile
f map (myFunction)(executionContext)

// does not compile
f map (item => println("sth."))(executionContext)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
f.map(myFunction)(executionContext)
```

In general, I find that using spaces instead of dots behaves unintuitively, so I try to avoid that unless I am copy-pasting an example.

Comment: That actually works! I did not try it with dot and without space ;-/ What a pity, I really started to like the space variant.

Answer (score 2):

FYI if you want to use the space syntax for the method invocation, you need to wrap the whole first part of the expression in parens:

```
(f map myFunction)(executionContext)
```

Otherwise the compiler thinks you're trying to pass the `executionContext` to `myFunction` instead of the function returned by `f map myFunction`.